# How to use child routes in eager loaded components (without touching

Tags: angular, routes, eager-loading

I see many tutorials using RouterModule.forChild(..) when it comes to lazy loading.  I believe this forChild can be used for eager loading as well, and its advantage is that the routes can be configured in the feature module, without touching the root module.

But now, i am using angular 15, and without using any ng module. Currently all my feature and root routes are configured in the main.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...productRoutes,  <--feature routes
  {path:'cart',component:CartComponent},
  {path:'**', component:PageNotFoundComponent}

];
providers:[provideRouter(app_routes)]
```

How do I configure feature routes (eager loaded) without modifying the main.ts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the follow way:

```
// app.routes.ts

import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'home'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },

    // Option 1: Lazy Loading another Routing Config
    {
        path: 'flight-booking',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./booking/flight-booking.routes')
                .then(m => m.FLIGHT_BOOKING_ROUTES)
    },

    // Option 2: Directly Lazy Loading a Standalone Component
    {
        path: 'next-flight',
        loadComponent: () => 
            import('./next-flight/next-flight.component')
                .then(m => m.NextFlightComponent)
    },
    [...]
];
```

Here you can lazy load a child `Routing` file, or you can lazy load a component directly. the `loadChildren` and `loadComponent` methods are your friend and they come from Angular itself.

[Here](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/routing-and-lazy-loading-with-standalone-components/) is a Article about this code from *Angular Architects*.

Comment: Thanks! However,  i am looking for dealing with eager loading, not lazy loading

Comment: Yes sorry. But if you add children (App.Component) the eager loading is the "default". So it works with Standalone Components in the same way as with Modules.

Answer (score 0):

Above is for lazy loading I think

```js
{ 
  path: 'PATH_GIVEN', component: ProductDetails,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'overview', component: Overview },
      { path: 'specs', component: Specs }
    ]
 }
```

This is the way for defining child path in Eager loading

Here's the [article](https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/child_routes)

Comment: Thanks. But the article never mention what to do after defining the routes. For your above snippet, how can the application recognize your defined routes? Before standalone component is introduced, we can put your routes inside the feature angular module using RouteModule.forChild(routes).  But now without involving angular module, I wonder how we can do that.